# Generate Google map link with nearby restaurants

Tags: google-maps, geolocation, location, maps

Is there a way to generate a google map link which takes in lat , long values and shows me the place along with the nearby restaurants. Using the places API i get the required response but i get that in JSON format i require a link where you click and it opens up the google maps and shows your respective location and all the nearby restaurants.

If you use this link
http://maps.google.com/?q=lat,long it would show me the location corresponding to the lat,long along with that can i also pass in some parameter to locate the nearby restaurants as well something like http://maps.google.com/?q=lat,lng&nearBy=restaurant

Comment: What is the reason for down voting ?????????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it can be of help to anyone who is facing a similar problem as i was.  Found out a way to generate a google link which points to the google maps with nearby restaurants(any field you want to search for can be replaced with the restaurant string)

```
http://www.google.com/maps/search/restaurant/@your_latitude,your_longitude,17z
```

You can replace the /restaurant/ with /bank/ and get the nearby banks to the latitude,longitude specified in the link

```
http://www.google.com/maps/search/bank/@your_latitude,your_longitude,17z
```

17 is the zoom level you can change that as per your requirement.

Comment: Any way to do it using a street address?